# Как вытаскивать из стека нужные значения?

Tags: ассемблер, стек

Я сначала сохраняю `PUSH EAX`, потом `PUSH EAX`, то есть значения двух регистров. Возможно, есть специальная инструкция, которая позволяет взять самое нижнее значение стэка? Вершиной стэка - значение `EAX`, дно стэка значение `ECX`. Как взять значение из "дна", изменить его и положить обратно на дно?
Благодарю за ответы!

Comment: На то он и стек чтобы с ним работали как со стеком. Если нужно самое нижнее, сохраняйте все до неё и потом обратно формируйте стек.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Машинный стек - это просто участок памяти, с ним можно работать как с любым другим участком памяти, например с помощью команды `mov` можно обратиться к любому адресу выше текущей вершины (адреса, лежащего в `esp`).

Действия из вопроса можно выполнить так:

```
push eax
push ecx
mov edx, [esp+4] ; берем значение, которое было добавлено в стек предпоследним
... ; как-то меняем
mov [esp+4], edx ; кладем обратно
```

Дном стека для процедуры условно можно считать значение указателя стека, которое он имеет в момент входа в процедуру. Есть стандартный прием, когда это значение сохраняется в регистр `ebp`, потом в стеке выделяется память под локальные переменные (указатель стека просто уменьшается на размер локальных переменных), а потом в процессе работы процедуры от `ebp` в большую сторону (`[ebp+N]`) рассчитываются адреса аргументов процедуры, а в меньшую сторону (`[ebp-N]`) - адреса локальных переменных. При этом значение `esp` в процессе работы процедуры может меняться, а значение `ebp` остается одним и тем же. Код процедуры будет выглядеть примерно так:

```
; Стандартный пролог для создания стекового фрейма
push ebp
mov ebp, esp
sub esp, M ; M - размер локальных переменных

... ; основной код процедуры

; Стандартный эпилог
mov esp, ebp
pop ebp
ret
```